# Unable to scroll RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView inside BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-bottomsheetdialog

The problem is whenever i try to scroll `RecyclerView`, `BottomSheet` scrolls

**Main Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">


    <include layout="@layout/layout_map_view" />

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bs_days_activities" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**layout_map_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_bs_days_activities.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager=".utils.customviews.LinearLayoutManagerWrapper"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_day" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_activities"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why used BottomSheet below MapView? Best way to use Bottom sheet is creating a new `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and call whenever you wanted. Check out [this blog](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/) or you can refer any other bottom sheet example.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting focusableOnTouchMode=true in your RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a late answer but for anyone facing the same issue as i did to solve this issue you need to add this attribute to your recyclerview.

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

then you need to go to your kotlin code and apply this touch listener on the recyclerview

```
binding.rvActivities.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        v.onTouchEvent(event)
        true
    }
```

that is the best solution that worked for me.

**Be sure that your layout matches the layout in the answer where your recycerlview is inside NestedScrollView and thay are all inside bottom dialog**